# Change taxonomy term field into text field in content-type

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, nodes, 7

Is there a way to transform a taxonomy term field into a simple text field? I need to keep all the terms present in the taxonomy field and have them separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I simply used a PHP script I execute in `mysite/devel/php` to copy my taxonomy term field value to my new text field:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'contact'));
foreach($nodes as $node) {
  if ($node != NULL) {
    $tid = $node->field_title['und'][0]['tid'];
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
    $name = $term->name;
    $node->field_function_title['und'][0]['value'] = $name;
    $node = node_submit($node);
    node_save($node);
  }
}
```